# Issues with Parentheses and Declaring an Array Using sqlplus and Shell Scripting

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, syntax-error, sh

I am getting a "**Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "}")**" error when creating a variable within my script.  I am looking to get the output from sqlplus and returning it as an array.  This is the function I am using:

```
get_list() {
ip=$1
port=$2
db_user=$3
db_pass=$4    

names_array=(`sqlplus -S $db_user/$db_pass@$ip:$port << EOF
    set heading off
    set feedback off;
    select username from users;
EOF`)

element=0
while [ $element -lt  ${names_array[*]} ]
    do
       echo ${element}") "${names_array[$element]}
       let element=$element+1;
    done
printf "\n\n"
read -p "Choice:" selection

sqlplus -S $db_user/$db_pass@$ip:$port << EOF
   drop user ${names_array[$selection]};
   quit;
EOF


}
```

The error occurs when I declare the array here.  This is the parenthesis that bash is complaining about:

```
names_array=(`sqlplus -S $db_user/$db_pass@$ip:$port << EOF
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are not supported in some shells (sh, dash). Use bash which supports them.

I can replicate the error in dash:

```
arr=(`cat << EOF
a
b
c
EOF`)
dash: 11: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
```

In bash, the code works without problems:

```
arr=(`cat << EOF
a
b
c
EOF` )
echo ${arr[1]}
```

Output:

```
b
```